# The string 'null' appears at the beginning of my CSV output

Tags: apex, batch, csv, string, escape

I am trying to create a CSV in the batch.

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    for(ID a: temp)
    {
        String recordString = '"'+a+'"\n';
        finalstring = finalstring + recordString;
    }
    Blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(finalstring);
}
```

I'm able to form the CSV file, but the first record has extra characters added to the value like this:

> null"001R000001dasdsadU"

I'm sure **recordString** has issues. How should I escape in a string?

Comment: You need to define finalString as a empty string and then check. String defineString = '';

Comment: Um. What are you trying to do? What is the problem? I find your question very difficult to follow.

Comment: @Devendra Thanks, your solution helped! I missed that out! Please add it as an answer.

Comment: @AdrianLarson My batch class deletes records and emails a csv file of the record Ids. When I open the csv file, the first record would show as .. https://s4.postimg.io/b9wrg3zd9/9_19_2016_5_34_38_PM.png . It was a minor issue which devendra already answered. Sorry I couldn't be clear enough :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to initialize finalString.

It would be,

```
String defineString = '';
```